# Find n largest values in a vector

Tags: c++

I currently have a vector and need to find the n largest numbers in it. For example, a user enters 5, i gotta run through it and output the 5 largest. Problem is, i can not sort this vector due to other constraints. Whats the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the constrains?

Comment: `std::nth_element` seems good for your situation if the order they're printed doesn't matter. If the order does matter, try a `std::partial_sort`. There's even `std::partial_sort_copy`, which leaves the original vector untouched and doesn't require you to copy all of it.

Comment: Cannot sort due to other vectors relying on this vectors index's.

Comment: Are you supposed to write the actual code, or are you supposed to "come up with something that solves the problem"?

Comment: No this is a real function of a c++ project. Im going to need to write it

Comment: You can do that in linear time by keeping a vector of at most `n` items. You run through each element of your list, compare them with the elements in your vector of big values, and replace smaller values with bigger values as you pass through your list.

Comment: @zneak: That's pretty much my answer...

Answer (score 9):

Based on your description of not modifying the original vector and my assumption that you want the order to matter, I suggest [`std::partial_sort_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy):

```
//assume vector<int> as source
std::vector<int> dest(n); //largest n numbers; VLA or std::dynarray in C++14
std::partial_sort_copy(
    std::begin(source), std::end(source), //.begin/.end in C++98/C++03
    std::begin(dest), std::end(dest), 
    std::greater<int>() //remove "int" in C++14
);
//output dest however you want, e.g., std::copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Is copying and sorting an option? I mean if your application is not that performance critical, this is the simplest (and asymptotically **not** too bad) way to go!

Comment: The algorithms I commented are just as simple, so might as well use them instead of sorting the entire thing for no reason. I do agree that copying it shouldn't be a huge issue, though.

Comment: wouldnt partial sort mutate the vector?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (`A` is incoming vector, `N` the number largest you want to find, `v` becomes the result vector):

```
vector<T> v(N, 0);   
for each element in A:
   if (element > v[N-1])
       for(i = N-1; i > 0 && v[i] < element; i--)
          v[i] = v[i-1];
       v[i] = element;
```

This is some sort of "pseudo-C++", not exactly C++, but hopefully describes how you'd do this.

Comment: For what I understood, you are keeping a sorted vector (v) and only comparing new elements with the highest element on this sorted vector. My question is: What happens when a new element is to be sorted, but its values is between the minimum and maximum from this sorted vector?

Comment: Unless I got my comparison the wrong way around, it should be "lowest index is highest value", so the comparison with the `v[N-1]` is to find the "lowest of the high values yet collected", and then insert it at the right place. I didn't implement full C++ code, so there may be small bugs in what I wrote, but the idea should be sound.